# How to consume internal endpoint in Azure.

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, endpoint

I've figured out how to create a WCF service exposed internally but have absolutely no idea how to consume this service from another web role or web app?

I have come across some examples that answer this exact scenario but the links explaining more info all seem to be dead.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us imagine this scenario:

You have a WCF services hosted in a worker role with internal endpoint. It implements the contract ICalculator which is a simple Calculator(ADD,Mult...etc).

on the other end you have a Webform app when button Clicked you just send  some data to be calculated.

here is the code for consuming this webservice:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<WorkerHost.ICalculator>(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None));
        var channel = factory.CreateChannel(GetRandomEndpoint());
        Label3.Text =channel.Add (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) , Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)).ToString();

    }
```

and the code for getRanDomeEndpoint() is

```
  private EndpointAddress GetRandomEndpoint()
    {
        var endpoints= RoleEnvironment.Roles["WorkerHost"].Instances.Select(i=>i.InstanceEndpoints["CalculatorService"].IPEndpoint).ToArray();
        var r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        return new EndpointAddress(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/Calculate", endpoints[r.Next(endpoints.Count() - 1)]));
    }
```

I have uploaded the service on azure check it out here

http://workerrolewcf.cloudapp.net/default.aspx

Comment: Thank you for an easy to follow example. Different question do internal tcp services have to be exposed via a worker role? or can they be exposed via a web role?

Comment: They are used for inter-role communication so you can either expose them via Web or Worker Role 
For most cases, they are used for Worker Role since Web role is already hosted in IIS